# atom-beautify: indent html with tabs

Tags: atom-editor, atom-beautify

How can I set the indent size of html to tab in atom-beautifier ?
I tried the following in .jscsrc but it doesn't have any effect.

```
{
  "html": {
    "indent_char": "    ",
    "indent_size": 1,
    "indent_with_tabs": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `atom-beautifier` package is deprecated and the author has suggested that users migrate to the [`atom-beautify` package](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify):

> Please use: https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify It's much better :)

The `atom-beautify` package supports a `.jsbeautifyrc` to configure the indent size:

```
{
  "indent_size": 2,
  "indent_char": " ",
  "other": " ",
  "indent_level": 0,
  "indent_with_tabs": false,
  "preserve_newlines": true,
  "max_preserve_newlines": 2,
  "jslint_happy": true,
  "indent_handlebars": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{
    "indent_char": "    ", //Tab here. Make sure editor doesn't change it. 
    "indent_size": 1,
    "indent_with_tabs": true
}`

I've put this at `$ATOMPATH/packages/atom-beautify/.jsbeautifyrc` AND `$ATOMPATH/packages/atom-beautify/src/.jsbeautifyrc`.

`atom-beautify` is still buggy as heck with tabs.  Also make sure that you turn off "soft tabs" in Atom.

Here's a gist of some tips for killing spaces:

https://gist.github.com/zamicol/c5c926500ddde49006122f9e4e52e48f